# css flex-box wrap elements going out of view port

Tags: css, flexbox

Im facing a problem with css flex box. attaching the link for example [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/stah7qb4/1/). In the example, parent element has 8 child elements. when max-height is specified, it wraps to next column but it is going out of view port. I need the parent element to be fixed and right aligned.

```css
.child {
  width: 72px;
  height: 72px;
}

.parent {
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  max-height: 60%;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child" style="background: red"></div>
  <div class="child" style="background: blue"></div>
  <div class="child" style="background: green"></div>
  <div class="child" style="background: pink"></div>
  <div class="child" style="background: aqua"></div>
  <div class="child" style="background: grey"></div>
  <div class="child" style="background: tomato"></div>
  <div class="child" style="background: skyblue"></div>
</div>
```

PS: Need a solution with out using width and writing-mode css properties.

Answer (score 0):

As visible in the screenshot `.parent`'s width is only 1 block, that's why it cuts off half of them. To make the children into two columns, you are better off adding two extra `div`s to create them into two columns as following

[image]

```css
.child {
  width: 72px;
  height: 72px;
}

.parent {
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  display: flex;
  /* change to column to put them all under eachother */
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="col">
    <div class="child" style="background: red"></div>
    <div class="child" style="background: blue"></div>
    <div class="child" style="background: green"></div>
    <div class="child" style="background: pink"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <div class="child" style="background: aqua"></div>
    <div class="child" style="background: grey"></div>
    <div class="child" style="background: tomato"></div>
    <div class="child" style="background: skyblue"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Let me know if this answered your question, if it didn't please let me know so I can look into it further.

Answer (score 0):

this will work

```css
.child {
  width: 72px;
  height: 72px;
}

.parent {
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  width:150px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction:row;
  /* change to column to put them all under eachother */
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child" style="background: red"></div>
    <div class="child" style="background: blue"></div>
    <div class="child" style="background: green"></div>
    <div class="child" style="background: pink"></div>
    <div class="child" style="background: aqua"></div>
    <div class="child" style="background: grey"></div>
    <div class="child" style="background: tomato"></div>
    <div class="child" style="background: skyblue"></div>
</div>
```